# What is the correct keyword for this line of code?

Tags: python

The purpose of the code is to extract the a number from a text file which is assigned to a variable called 3;

The code:

```
with open(three) as f:
    the_list = [int(l.strip().split()[1]) for l in f]
```

Can someone explain the reason as to why the text file is abbreviated to the letter 'f'.
and `the_list = [int(l.strip().split()[1]) for l in f]`

Comment: Please stop mangling your questions after they've been answered: your edits render the answers meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a short name. You can use any valid name you want following the `as` keyword. Here, a short, one-letter name is used because there is no need to emphasize what the name of the file object actually is.

The second line creates a list of integers stored in the second field of each line of the file. Your input file looks something like

```
foo 3
hello 17
whatever 0
```

which produces a list like

```
[3, 17, 0]
```

(`l.strip()` removes leading and trailing whitespace from the line; `split()` creates a list consisting of the whitespace-separated fields, which is indexed to grab the second field; and the result is passed to `int` to produce an `int` object from the string.)

Comment: Thanks! is it possible you can give me an explanation of the second line of the code? Great explanation btw!

Comment: Can you please please explain the second line for me?

Comment: Bro, has anyone ever said ur amazing, and your explanation is on point, bro your rep is on point as well, thanks again!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! <3 much <3 i understand fully

Comment: @chepner: please add 2 spaces after each data pair in your example to have them on 3 lines; otherwise the explanation of your code (linewise) is not easy to understand.(I couldn't edit it although I added 6 blanks, looks like blanks don't count...)

Comment: Fixed. Those were supposed to be indented 4 spaces to produce pre-formatted output, but I only had 3 spaces.

Comment: btw i understood first time dw, i saw through the mistake ;). @chepner